# Apache logging twice to /proc/1/fd/1

Tags: docker, apache2

I am trying to use tee to log into two locations:

- file in persistent storage
- Docker stdout

Error log line from VirtualHost config:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache/error.log /proc/1/fd/1"
```

Now the problem is that errors are logged twice in /proc/1/fd/1 (as docker logs states), yet error is only logged once into /var/log/apache/error.log

I´ve also tried run from cli:

```
echo 123 | /usr/bin/tee -a /tmp/test /proc/1/fd/1
```

This succesfully writes only once to both file and stdout.

Is there some reason why Apache logs writes twice to /proc/1/fd/1 while it logs only once to file and /usr/bin/tee also works as expected?

Comment: What image are you using, and how do you start the containers?  Is the `error.log` file actually a symlink to `/dev/fd/1` or something similar?

Comment: Using php:8.0.23-apache image and error.log is not symlink. I had same guess that for some reason I have made symlink out of /proc/1/fd/1, but no effect changing first filename of Errorlog directive. Also shouldn't echo & tee test also didn't log twice.